# Does there exist Latin square critical sets for which deleting any entry results in arbitrarily many completions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, latin-square

For those familiar with [Latin squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) terminology, I'll get straight to the point:

> *Q*: For all $N \geq 2$, does there exists a critical set $C$ (for a Latin square of any finite order) such that deleting an entry from $C$ always results in $\geq N$ completions?

I'm guessing the answer is yes, but it doesn't strike me as obvious how to construct such critical sets.  (Although, as always, I could be missing something.)

---

For those who aren't familiar (or who are rusty, or use different terminology)...

A *partial Latin square* is an $n \times n$ matrix with symbols from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and possibly some empty cells in which no symbol is repeated in a row or column.

A Latin square $L=(l_{ij})$ is said to be a *completion* of a partial Latin square $P=(p_{ij})$ if $l_{ij}=p_{ij}$ whenever cell $(i,j)$ in $P$ is nonempty.

A *critical set* is a partial Latin square $P$ that (a) admits a unique completion, and (b) admits $\geq 2$ completions after deleting any entry.

Here is an example of a critical set:
$$\begin{array}{|cccc|}
\hline
4 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 2 \\
\cdot & 3 & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & 1 & \cdot \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
which admits the unique completion
$$\begin{array}{|cccc|}
\hline
4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{array}.$$

If we delete the $1$ in the top row of the critical set, it admits the alternative completion
$$\underbrace{\begin{array}{|cccc|}
\hline
4 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 2 \\
\cdot & 3 & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & 1 & \cdot \\
\hline
\end{array}}_{\text{exactly } 2 \text{ completions}}
\xrightarrow{\text{also completes to}}
\begin{array}{|cccc|}
\hline
4 & \color{blue} 2 & 3 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{array}.$$
It admits no other completions.

I would like, for arbitrary $N \geq 2$, to construct critical sets in which deleting any entry always results in $\geq N$ completions (if possible).

Comment: I think that this question is very difficult. Too bad [Douglas S. Stones](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/139/douglas-s-stones) hasn't been seen for half a year or so. He is/was our expert in latin squares and might no more about this. This is IMHO a research level question, so you may have better luck in MathOverflow.